# IPsec tunnel between 2 remote host

Tags: ipsec, iproute2

I'm using mininet, I have created a ESP tunnel between two machine such that if I ping from one machine to other then I am seeing ESP packets, and everything works fine. Here below the commands used:

```
M1 ip xfrm policy add dir out src 2001:0:0:1c::2 dst 2001:0:0:1c::1 tmpl proto esp mode transport
M1 ip xfrm state add src 2001:0:0:1c::2 dst 2001:0:0:1c::1 proto esp spi 1 enc 'cbc(aes)' 0x3ed0af408cf5dcbf5d5d9a5fa806b224 mode transport

M2 ip xfrm policy add dir in src 2001:0:0:1c::2 dst 2001:0:0:1c::1 tmpl proto esp mode transport
M2 ip xfrm state add src 2001:0:0:1c::2 dst 2001:0:0:1c::1 proto esp spi 1 enc 'cbc(aes)' 0x3ed0af408cf5dcbf5d5d9a5fa806b224 mode transport
```

Now what I am trying to do is that:

I have 2 machines, say M1 and M3 that are remote(or smt like M1-->M2-->M3 for instance) and I'm just changing the respective src and dst with the ipv6 addr, but in this case the tunnel doesn't work anymore, I mean seeing the packets on wireshark the ESP header is not present. Even if i leave the code as above the packets between M1 and M2 are still without the ESP header.

My goal is to have an IPsec comunication bewtween M1 and M3, so If I Ping from M1 to M3 there would be ESP packets between M1 and M3 and packet between MC2 and MC3. How can I implement that? any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want to encrypt communication between M1 and M3 directly? Is there some address translation involved?

Comment: I have a segment routing configuration, so in my case dst of ipv6 is not the final destination but the final destination is inside the segment routing header.

Answer (score 3):

First a disclaimer: setting up encryption keys manually is perfect for demonstration purposes, but and **IKE** daemon like [strongSwan](https://www.strongswan.org/) will do it better and is not more difficult to configure.

The commands you used in your question imply that:

- you set up encryption only in one direction (M1 -> M2). The ESP packets you see with WireShark are those going out of M1 and into M2. The reply to the ping is unencrypted,
- you use only encryption without authentication, so you can't detect if your packets were modified (e.g. truncated) in transit,
- you use **transport** mode, so you can use the encrypted channel to send packets from M1 to M2, but not further.
- you probably use always an **spi** of 1. This is the number that is sent with every ESP packets and allows the kernel to distinguish between encrypted channels.

So if you want to establish a bidirectional encrypted channel, you need to generate an **spi** and encryption key for both directions:

```
host1="2001:0:0:1c::2"
host2="2001:0:0:1c::1"
key12=0x$(xxd -c 32 -l 32 -ps /dev/random)
key21=0x$(xxd -c 32 -l 32 -ps /dev/random)
spi12=0x$(xxd -c 4 -l 4 -ps /dev/random)
spi21=0x$(xxd -c 4 -l 4 -ps /dev/random)
```

Then you need to install the encryption keys on both hosts:

```
ip xfrm state add src $host1 dst $host2 proto esp spi $spi12 enc 'cbc(aes)' $key12 mode transport
ip xfrm state add src $host2 dst $host1 proto esp spi $spi21 enc 'cbc(aes)' $key21 mode transport
```

Once the keys are installed you can add policies, so Linux will start encrypting data. The instructions differ between hosts (obviously), because the directions **in** and **out** are different. On M1 you need to use:

```
ip xfrm policy add dir out src $host1 dst $host2 tmpl proto esp mode transport
ip xfrm policy add dir in src $host2 dst $host1 tmpl proto esp mode transport
```

while on M2:

```
ip xfrm policy add dir in src $host1 dst $host2 tmpl proto esp mode transport
ip xfrm policy add dir out src $host2 dst $host1 tmpl proto esp mode transport
```

Now the kernel will start encrypting outgoing packets and drop unencrypted incoming packets.

If something does not work, check if firewalls are letting ESP pass through.

PS: You can find a [more complete solution](https://backreference.org/2014/11/12/on-the-fly-ipsec-vpn-with-iproute2/) on [waldner's blog](https://backreference.org/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved. It was a problem in my kernel version. Your instructions was very clear and helpful anyway.